# RecyclerAdapter - can't set long & normal click listeners to parent and child

Tags: android, onclicklistener, viewgroup, onlongclicklistener, viewchild

I have a simple `RecyclerView` with a row item containing one image.

I want to set a normal `onClickListener` to the ImageView and a `longClickListener` to the `itemView` itself.

The issue is that when doing so - they can't seem to live together with each other. if I assign both a long click for parent viewGroup and click for child `imageView` - only the child click works. If I remove the code of the normal click listener only than the long click one starts to work.

Here is my adapter -

```java
public class HorizontalRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_row_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.imageView.getContext(), "Long Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.imageView.getContext(), "Normal Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView imageView;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

edit -

here is my xml row item -

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have given match_parent to imageview height and width. in that case itemview will not catch the click event because imageview will catch it before that. if you so, set long click too on the imageview.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not act the same as I wanted. I want all views inside the viewholder to also catch long pressed and do the same logic, that without having any problems listening to normal clicks.

Comment: I may help you better if you add xml of the adapter item.

Comment: What you can do is set click listener on the image. and log click listener on image as well as itemview and do same action for both long clicks.

Answer (score 0):

First - it's a basic mistake of beginner to use OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder. Use my solution, that solve your issue and bonus: save you from memory leaks.

1) Create this class:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
}
```

2) Attach it to your RecyclerView:

```
yourRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(context, yourRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //do some work
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //do some work
                    }
                }));
```

Good luck!

Comment: The issue with your solution is that I am trying to set the normal click listener to the IMAGE, and the long click listener to the parent VIEWHOLDER itself - your implementation gives me both normal & long click listeners to the entire row item.

Comment: Anyway, I would be happy if you can explain why this solution is better than mine? memory leak wise etc.

Comment: Because if your create OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder than you will have as many objects as the items in your recycler view. 100 items = 100 click listeners. In my solution there is only one listener object